# Algorithm to find next number in sequence

Tags: javascript, jquery

sequence: 1,2,3,...10
formula: x = n+1

suppose sequence is an array and at a given time sequence contain 1,3,5 on first three indexes remaining contain 0

now next number should be 2 and array will have 1,2,3,5 on first four indexes remaining contain 0

now next number should be 4 and array will have 1,2,3,4,5 on first five indexes remaining contain 0

now next number should be 6 and array will have 1,2,3,5,6 on first six indexes remaining contain 0

```
function findNextNumber(numArry) {
    var number = 1;
    var tempArray = new Array();
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        tempArray[i] = "E";
    }
    $.each(numArry, function () {
        if (this != 0) {
            tempArray[this] = "F"
        }
    });
    $.each(tempArray, function (index) {
        if (this == "E") {
            number = index + 1;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return number;
}
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Post your code and the issues you have faced.

Comment: I have a solution but that doesn't seems time efficient

Comment: You are adding a new number and you want to put them in sequence, rest of the indexes should contain 0. Is that what you want?

Comment: @TariqMahmood: You should include your code in the question. The comment section is only suitable for limited snippets of code.

Comment: You need to know the algorithm only?

Comment: what about memory efficiency? is it always 0..10?

Comment: Just break the loop as soon as you find the right index and then run the loop from that index in order to move greater values one index ahead.

Comment: @clph3r, yes it is always 1-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function nextHole(array,until) {
      this.array=array;
      this.lastIndex=0;
      this.lastItem=0;
      this.until=until;
      this.loopFinished=false;
      this.done=false;
      this.reset = function(){
          this.lastIndex=0;
          this.lastItem=0;
          this.done=false;
          this.loopFinished=false;
      }

      this.getNext = function(){

        if (this.done){
            return null;
        }

        if (!this.loopFinished){                
            for(loop=this.lastIndex;loop<this.array.length ;loop++){
                if (this.array[loop]!=this.lastItem+1){

                    this.lastItem++;
                    this.lastIndex=loop;
                    if (this.lastItem>until)
                        break;


                    return this.lastItem;
                }else{
                    this.lastItem=this.array[loop];
                }

            }

        }
        this.loopFinished=true;
        if (this.lastItem < this.until){
            return (++this.lastItem);
        }
        this.done=true;
        return null;
      }

    }


    var h = new nextHole([1,2,5,6,7,15],10);
    while(true){
        var n = h.getNext();
        if (n == null){
            break;
        }else{
            console.log(" yield: "+n);
        }
    }


    h.reset();
    while(true){
        var n = h.getNext();
        if (n == null){
            break;
        }else{
            console.log(" yield: "+n);
        }
    }



</script>
```

Comment: note that this example does not exactly work as required if the array length is shorter than 10. Then it will not fill the rest.

Comment: ok, I updated the code, now it works as required

Answer (score 0):

Am I wrong or is it just the following?

```
function formula(n){ return n+1; }
var sequence = [1,3,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
var i=0;
function findNextNumber() {
    for (; i<10; i++) {
        var x = formula(i);
        if (sequence[i] != x) {
            sequence.splice(i, 0, x); // insert x here
            sequence.length = 10; // chop of rest
            return x;
        }
    }
    // else
    return null/undefined/whatever;
}

> findNextNumber()
2
> findNextNumber()
4
> findNextNumber()
6
> findNextNumber()
7
> findNextNumber()
8
> findNextNumber()
9
> findNextNumber()
10
> findNextNumber()
whatever
```